# Standard practice for writing Conda environment file with support for TensorFlow CPU/GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, virtual-environment

I would like to add an `environments.yml` file to my repo. Since I don't know whether the end user will be using the CPU or GPU version of TensorFlow, I am unsure how to proceed. My thoughts:

- I could create two environment files, each one for CPU/GPU
- I create one environment file for the more commonly used GPU variant and hope the users figure out what's going on

Is there a standard approach to this or a better way I haven't considered?

Comment: Do you know what OS user is using?

Comment: @FrenzyKiwi It could be any. I want the code to be accessible to as many users as reasonably possible

Comment: You'd have to script. Such interaction is not directly available on conda.